# Duplicate symbol in static library

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

I'm trying to compile an iOS project for the Simulator in XCode with a 3rd-party static library added to it and I get this linker error message complaining about duplicate symbols:

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Utility in:
>       libUIExtensions.a(Utility.o)
>       /Users/Joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PdfSampleProgram-cdoogvkqqrafetcvscffsrlgkvrr/Build/Intermediates/PdfSampleProgram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PdfSampleProgram.build/Objects-normal/i386/Utility.o
>
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Utility in:
>       libUIExtensions.a(Utility.o)
>       /Users/Joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PdfSampleProgram-cdoogvkqqrafetcvscffsrlgkvrr/Build/Intermediates/PdfSampleProgram.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PdfSampleProgram.build/Objects-normal/i386/Utility.o
>
> ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any idea what I could do with the project? I've only added the static library once to the project, the header files for the static libs seem ok. Am I missing something in the project settings?

There's another sample project were it compiles fine, but I just don't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Check duplicates in `Build Phases > Compile Sources`.

Answer (score 0):

There must be 2 same files in your project. You should check libraries or compile sources in build phase or check the project file through finder.